# How to optimize the part of my code that involves auto-executing methods, it is written in Python and uses tkinter for the gui

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, ocr

I wrote a small program for automatic translation using Python.
It works like this:

- By setting, you can use the clipboard or OCR to get the text to be translated.
- And we can choose two working methods: automatic (get the text and translate every once in a while) or manual (get the text translation is triggered by pressing a button)
- The obtained translation results will be drawn on the tkinter canvas.

The problem at the beginning was that when using automatic mode, due to the time-consuming problems of OCR and translation, the whole program does not run smoothly;

So I joined the threadPool to solve this problem.

And then, it is indeed much smoother by using the threadpool, but a new problem arises:

The translation results presented on the interface correspond to the last recognized text, not the currently displayed text.

It likes that:

| source | result |
| --- | --- |
| first | none |
| second | first |
| third | second |

---

Here is the relevant code:

<autoTrans> function to execute in loop in tkinter.

It's in MainGui class.

```
class MainGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.source_text = None
        self.result_text = None
        self.text_cache = ["", ""]
        self.inputCase = None  
        self.tsaCase = None  
        self.autoWorker = None

---------------Other unnecessary code omitted---------

    def autoTrans(self):
        if Global.auto:                                            # If auto switch is on
            if Global.start_pause:                                 # If the start and stop button is on(start)
                self.auto.start_source_task()                      # Run this thread
                if not Global.getsourceRunning:                    # If it is not in the state of getting(it mean scan complete)
                    self.source_text = self.auto.getSource()       # Get the text which saved in the GetSource class
                else:                                              # If it is in the state of getting (it mean scanning)
                    self.source_text = ""
                if self.source_text != "":                         # In the OCR method, I make some cases that can be skipped return ""
                    self.text_cache[0] = self.source_text          # If not "",We save the scan results to self.text_cache[0]
                    self.auto.start_result_task()
                    if not Global.getresultRunning:                # If it is not in the state of getting(it means translate complete)
                        self.result_text = self.auto.getResult()   # Get the text which saved in the GetResult class
                    else:                                          # If it is in the state of getting (it means translating)
                        self.result_text = ""
                    self.text_cache[1] = self.result_text          # We save the translate results to self.text_cache[1]
                else:                                              # If self.source_text is "sim",keep drawing with the last text
                    self.source_text = self.text_cache[0]
                    self.result_text = self.text_cache[1]
                self.drawText()
                self.autoWorker = self.after(400, self.autoTrans)  # Loop this function with a timer
            else:                                                  # Keep looping even in paused state,we can switch to start at any time
                self.autoWorker = self.after(400, self.autoTrans)
        else:                                                      # When automatic mode is turned off. Remove timer completely
            if self.autoWorker:
                self.after_cancel(self.autoWorker)
                self.autoWorker = None

#self.drawText function is responsible for drawing self.source_text and self.result_text to the tk interface
```

---

**AutoWork class**

```
"""
I used getsourceRunning and getresultRunning to mark the running status
of the function so that the correct output
self.root.inputCase will be created when the user selects
Both clipboard and OCR will have gettext function
self.root.tsaCase.translate is also the same
"""

class Autowork:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
        self.source_task = None
        self.result_task = None
        self.source = None
        self.result = None

    def start_source_task(self):
        if self.source_task is None or self.source_task.done():
            self.source_task = self.executor.submit(self.get_source)

    def start_result_task(self):
        if self.result_task is None or self.result_task.done():
            self.result_task = self.executor.submit(self.get_result)

    def get_source(self):
        Global.getsourceRunning = True
        self.source = self.root.inputCase.gettext()
        Global.getsourceRunning = False

    def get_result(self):
        Global.getresultRunning = True
        self.result = self.root.tsaCase.translate(self.root.source_text, Global.language)
        Global.getresultRunning = False

    def getSource(self):
        return self.source

    def getResult(self):
        return self.result
```

---

This method of using threads may be stupid, so my program just works but not well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using threads for this purpose isn't silly at all. It's a standard technique for this kind of time consuming background task.

You just need to be doing two things:

1. Make sure the translation thread schedule an UI update after it completed the translation
2. Use a "debouncer" to squash multiple translation updates while one is already being processed and sometimes to also rate limit the update event (e.g. preventing more than 1 translation request every second). Once the source text is no longer actively changed, the debouncer should perform one last translation update

There are a number of different techniques to implement a debouncer. Google up for that term "tkinter debouncer" to see a number of examples of how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I modified part of the judgment logic, and now the text and translation content can be synchronized.So this problem seems to be closed

```
def autoTrans(self):
    if Global.auto:
        if Global.start_pause:
            self.auto.start_source_task()               
            if not Global.getsourceRunning:             
                self.source_text = self.auto.source
            else:
                self.source_text = ""
            if self.source_text != "":                  
                self.text_cache[0] = self.source_text   
                self.auto.start_result_task()           
            if not Global.getresultRunning:             
                self.result_text = self.auto.getResult()
                self.text_cache[1] = self.result_text
            self.source_text = self.text_cache[0]       
            self.result_text = self.text_cache[1]

            self.drawText()
            self.autoWorker = self.after(250, self.autoTrans)
        else:
            self.autoWorker = self.after(250, self.autoTrans)
    else:
        if self.autoWorker:
            self.after_cancel(self.autoWorker)
            self.autoWorker = None
```